# Group project uses both NPM + Yarn. How to transition to use only one?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

As title indicates, I'm working on a project where different members have used different tools (NPM and Yarn) for handling packages and modules etc.

We aim to transition to use ONLY Yarn (not our decision). Would anyone be able to share resources detailing how to accomplish such a thing? Or help quickly walk me through the steps?

I tried googling for answers but every single result is yet another article explaining why you should ditch NPM/Yarn and move your project to Yarn/NPM, without explaining the steps one would need to take to move from using both to just one mid-project. Thanks!

Comment: This depends entirely on how your project is structured. You'll need to give information about the architecture to get any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Yarn has a page talking about how to migrate to it from NPM:

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/

> In most cases, running yarn or yarn add for the first time will just work. In some cases, the information in a package.json file is not explicit enough to eliminate dependencies, and the deterministic way that Yarn chooses dependencies will run into dependency conflicts. This is especially likely to happen in larger projects where sometimes npm install does not work and developers are frequently removing node_modules and rebuilding from scratch. If this happens, try using npm to make the versions of dependencies more explicit, before converting to Yarn.
>
> As of Yarn 1.7.0, you can import your package-lock.json state, generated by npm to Yarn, by using yarn import.

They use many of the same files and structures.  The important thing is to check-in the yarn.lock file and make sure everyone is installing using Yarn instead of NPM.

If you have a build server, you could probably use it to enforce those dependencies, but it would be more work.